# Proper use of json_table in mariadb json

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I want to transform a json column called `words` inside a database table called `data_table` into a table. The content of the column is:

```
{"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"},
 "78910":{"first":"All good?"}
}
```

I want to reach sth like this output:

```
ID     | word     |
-------+----------|
123456 |hello     |
-------+----------|
78910  |All good? |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table t1,
JSON_TABLE( t1.words, '$.123456.*' COLUMNS (word PATH '$.first')) AS jt;
```

But it returns a #1064 mysql syntax error. Where is the error???

COMPLETE ERROR CODE (translated from german):

```
Error in the SQL-Syntax. Please consult the manual for the correct syntax near '( t1.words, '$.123456.*' COLUMNS (word PATH '$.first')) AS jt LIMIT 0, 25' in line 2
```

I moreover noticed that the basic example of [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM
JSON_TABLE(
    '[ {"c1": null} ]',
    '$[*]' COLUMNS( c1 INT PATH '$.c1' ERROR ON ERROR )
) as jt;
```

Also returns a #1064 syntax error (translated from german):

```
#1064 - There's an error in your SQL-Syntax. Please consult the manual for the correct syntax near '(
    '[ {"c1": null} ]',
    '$[*]' COLUMNS( c1 INT PATH '$.c1' ERROR ON E...' on line 3
```

What's wrong??? Btw, my host says that my mysql version is 10.3-MariaDB..

**UPDATE**

No matter what I try here, I always get a #1064 mysql syntax error, telling me to correct my syntax near {whatever comes after `JSON_TABLE(` in my statement}. What is wrong??

According to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/function-differences-between-mariadb-103-and-mysql-80/), is JSON_TABLE actually not even available for me??

Comment: The 2nd part of the error message tells you where the error is (near ...)

Comment: That's what I don't get, it says ```near '( t1.words, '$.123456.*' COLUMNS (word '$.first')) AS jt```

Comment: Please Joe, ALWAYS show us ALL the error message, not a summary

Comment: Well it doesn't really say more than I said; added above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`JSON_TABLE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) feature was added in MariaDB 10.6.0.

The error reported for your SQL is due to the missing type for the value. The field definition should be:

```
COLUMNS (word TEXT PATH '$.first')
```

Additionally, if you want to inspect only a single column, you should use the parent object instead of matching each child object in the path expression:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table t1, JSON_TABLE(
  t1.words, '$.123456' COLUMNS (word TEXT PATH '$.first')
) AS jt;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| words                                                                        | word  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| {"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"}, "78910":{"first":"All good?"}} | hello |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

If you want to select all members and filter based on the content in the `WHERE` clause, you can use the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table t1, JSON_TABLE(
  t1.words, '$.123456.*' COLUMNS (word TEXT PATH '$')
) AS jt;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| words                                                                        | word  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| {"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"}, "78910":{"first":"All good?"}} | hello |
| {"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"}, "78910":{"first":"All good?"}} | there |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

The `$` path expression refers to the value itself and it is a useful for passing the JSON input as the output in JSON form.

If you want to extract the values for all objects that have the field *first*, use `$.*.first` as the path expression:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table t1, JSON_TABLE(
  t1.words, '$.*.first' COLUMNS (word TEXT PATH '$')
) AS jt;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| words                                                                        | word      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| {"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"}, "78910":{"first":"All good?"}} | hello     |
| {"123456":{"first":"hello","second":"there"}, "78910":{"first":"All good?"}} | All good? |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Cheers mate, I feel like the json_table() function was not supported back then 

Comment: Yes it is recently added in 10.6.0 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/

Answer (score 1):

It actually seems that MariaDB systems [do NOT support](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table-support/) the JSON_TABLE function supported in MySQL Servers...

Still, my host claims his "MySQL Version" to be "10.3-MariaDB", so I'm somewhat confused; I was told they have the same functionalities, and looks like I was misinformed? From what I've read online, MariaDB seems to be a re-implementation of MySQL, which improves a lot of MySQL Server's features, but lacks some of them, as for example the json_table function. Is that correct, or am I misunderstanding anything here, and I should indeed be able to use the json_table function?

Comment: Mariadb is a **fork** of mysql. They are binary compatible meaning both use the same protocol for communication purposes, so the same clients can connect to both types of servers. However, the server-side functionalities are increasingly different from each other. When you ask a question, you should really tag only that product that you use, not both - unless you are sure that the question is applicable to both products. In this case, it is not.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the fact that mysql server and mariadb servers share different mysql json functions, otherwise I would never have asked this question. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Well, you really should get to know your technology stack before you start using any piece of technology...

Answer (score 1):

As seen on your case, MariaDB has no support for `JSON_TABLE()` function. A workaround might be defined through generating rows along with number of keys within the json data by using `JSON_KEYS()` and `JSON_LENGTH()` functions recursively within a query having an auxiliary table such as from `information_schema` such as `information_schema.tables`, and use `JSON_QUERY()` with indexes(`CONCAT('$.',ID)`) to determine the values for the elements `first`, then `JSON_EXTRACT()` in order to extract the desired part, and lastly
`JSON_UNQUOTE()` to get rid of double-quotes :

```
WITH t1 AS
(
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS rn, 
       JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( JSON_KEYS(jsdata),CONCAT('$[',@i,']')) ) AS ID,
       jsdata
  FROM information_schema.tables AS t1 
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := -1, t.* FROM t) AS t2 -- t is your original table
 WHERE @i < JSON_LENGTH( JSON_KEYS(jsdata) ) - 1
) 
SELECT t1.ID, 
       JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( JSON_QUERY(jsdata, CONCAT('$.',ID)) ,"$.first") ) AS word
  FROM t1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=baf634c9734a9558b76e0c5acc27be54)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

JSON_TABLE was introduced in MariaDB 10.6.

See documentation and examples at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/